# How to match minimize length of strings around keyword by regex

Tags: regex

I have below string (one long string).

> {"type":"Execution","typeValue":"Custom","targetValue":"_self","params":{"_report":"reportname","hyperlinkInput":"2","Organization":"orgid","As_Of_Date":"2016-04-01"},"id":"1111","href":"href?hyperlinkInput=2&Organization=orgid&As_Of_Date=2016-04-01&Locale=en_US","selector":"ExecutionEnd"},{"type":"Execution","typeValue":"Custom","targetValue":"_self","params":{"_report":"reportname","hyperlinkInput":"2","Organization":"orgid","As_Of_Date":"2016-04-01","CustomerID":"2222"},"id":"1234","href":"href?hyperlinkInput=2&Organization=orgid&As_Of_Date=2016-04-01&CustomerID=2222&Locale=en_US","selector":"ExecutionEnd"},{"type":"Execution","typeValue":"Custom","targetValue":"_self","params":{"_report":"reportname","hyperlinkInput":"2","Organization":"orgid","As_Of_Date":"2016-04-01"},"id":"1112","href":"href?hyperlinkInput=2&Organization=orgid&As_Of_Date=2016-04-01&Locale=en_US","selector":"ExecutionEnd"},{"type":"Execution","typeValue":"Custom","targetValue":"_self","params":{"_report":"reportname","hyperlinkInput":"2","Organization":"orgid","As_Of_Date":"2016-04-01","CustomerID":"2223"},"id":"1235","href":"href?hyperlinkInput=2&Organization=orgid&As_Of_Date=2016-04-01&CustomerID=22223&Locale=en_US","selector":"ExecutionEnd"},

Please note:

1. The string is in one line and you could notice that in each {} pair, the content is very similar.
2. **I could only do it with regex** and cannot do any split by any functions.
3. I want to use regular expression to filter out the one containing CustomerID with minimum complete length. For example, I want to filter out as below.

> {"type":"Execution","typeValue":"Custom","targetValue":"_self","params":{"_report":"reportname","hyperlinkInput":"2","Organization":"orgid","As_Of_Date":"2016-04-01","CustomerID":"2222"},"id":"1234","href":"href?hyperlinkInput=2&Organization=orgid&As_Of_Date=2016-04-01&CustomerID=2222&Locale=en_US","selector":"ExecutionEnd"}
>
> {"type":"Execution","typeValue":"Custom","targetValue":"_self","params":{"_report":"reportname","hyperlinkInput":"2","Organization":"orgid","As_Of_Date":"2016-04-01","CustomerID":"2223"},"id":"1235","href":"href?hyperlinkInput=2&Organization=orgid&As_Of_Date=2016-04-01&CustomerID=22223&Locale=en_US","selector":"ExecutionEnd"},

But I'm not sure how to do this. I tried many times with zero width assertion but still cannot figure it out. Could you please enlighten me? Thanks!

Comment: @rock321987, thanks for the reply but please note, I could only do the filter with regex. I cannot use other parser or functions provided by 3rd party, This is due to the limitation of tools I'm using.

Comment: specify the tool that you are using

Comment: @rock321987 a load test tool implemented by ourselves. I'm seeking if there's any solution to get it done within regex. Thanks.

Comment: see **[this](https://regex101.com/r/mL5oW6/1)**..you have to do a substitution..don't know whether your tool provides that facility

Comment: @rock321987 Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, it does not support... Anyway, I spent 1 hour on this and I decide to write a wrapper to do the match. Thanks!

Comment: try this (\{\"type.*?ExecutionEnd\"\})/g

Comment: @rock321987 Oh yes finally find a work round for the substitution. Thanks.

Comment: if you want to only match, then it can be done easily but I think you also want a substitution

Answer (score 0):

## Forward

I don't recommend using Regex to parse JSON because of all the possible edge cases. But it appears you have some control over the data and can therefore limit the edge cases.

## Description

Based on your source text, this regex will do the following:

- Find all the JSON entries that have a `CustomerID` field in nested inside the `Params` array, and embeded inside the `href` string
- Validates that both the `CustomerID` located in `Params` and `href` are identical
- work with both compressed and expanded JSON
- Avoids some obvious edge cases that the regex police complain about

Note: running this regex I used the Case insensitive flag.

`\{(?=(?:"[^"]*"|[^{}"]*|\{[^{}]*})*?"params":\{(?:"[^"]*"|[^{}"]*|\{[^{}]*})*?"CustomerID":"([^"]*)")(?=(?:"[^"]*"|[^{}"]*|\{[^{}]*})*?"href":"[^"]*&CustomerID=\1)(?:"[^"]*"|[^{}"]*|\{[^{}]*})*}`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

To view the image better, right click the image and select open in new window.

## Examples

**Source Text**

```
{"type":"Execution","typeValue":"Custom","targetValue":"_self","params":{"_report":"reportname","hyperlinkInput":"2","Organization":"orgid","As_Of_Date":"2016-04-01"},"id":"1111","href":"href?hyperlinkInput=2&Organization=orgid&As_Of_Date=2016-04-01&Locale=en_US","selector":"ExecutionEnd"}
,{"type":"Execution","typeValue":"Custom","targetValue":"_self","params":{"_report":"reportname","hyperlinkInput":"2","Organization":"orgid","As_Of_Date":"2016-04-01","CustomerID":"2222"},"id":"1234","href":"href?hyperlinkInput=2&Organization=orgid&As_Of_Date=2016-04-01&CustomerID=2222&Locale=en_US","selector":"ExecutionEnd"},{"type":"Execution","typeValue":"Custom","targetValue":"_self","params":{"_report":"reportname","hyperlinkInput":"2","Organization":"orgid","As_Of_Date":"2016-04-01"},"id":"1112","href":"href?hyperlinkInput=2&Organization=orgid&As_Of_Date=2016-04-01&Locale=en_US","selector":"ExecutionEnd"},{"type":"Execution","typeValue":"Custom","targetValue":"_self","params":{"_report":"reportname","hyperlinkInput":"2","Organization":"orgid","As_Of_Date":"2016-04-01","CustomerID":"2223"},"id":"1235","href":"href?hyperlinkInput=2&Organization=orgid&As_Of_Date=2016-04-01&CustomerID=22223&Locale=en_US","selector":"ExecutionEnd"},

{"type":"Execution","typeValue":"Custom","targetValue":"_self","params":{"_report":"reportname","hyperlinkInput":"2","Organization":"orgid","As_Of_Date":"2016-04-01","CustomerID":"44444"},"id":"1235","href":"href?hyperlinkInput=2&Organization=orgid&As_Of_Date=2016-04-01&CustomerID=44444&Locale=en_US","selector":"ExecutionEnd"},
```

**Matches**

```
[0][0] = {"type":"Execution","typeValue":"Custom","targetValue":"_self","params":{"_report":"reportname","hyperlinkInput":"2","Organization":"orgid","As_Of_Date":"2016-04-01","CustomerID":"2222"},"id":"1234","href":"href?hyperlinkInput=2&Organization=orgid&As_Of_Date=2016-04-01&CustomerID=2222&Locale=en_US","selector":"ExecutionEnd"}
[0][1] = 2222

[1][0] = {"type":"Execution","typeValue":"Custom","targetValue":"_self","params":{"_report":"reportname","hyperlinkInput":"2","Organization":"orgid","As_Of_Date":"2016-04-01","CustomerID":"44444"},"id":"1235","href":"href?hyperlinkInput=2&Organization=orgid&As_Of_Date=2016-04-01&CustomerID=44444&Locale=en_US","selector":"ExecutionEnd"}
[1][1] = 44444
```

## Explained

**Capture Groups**

- group 0 gets the entire matching JSON block
- group 1 gets the value associated with `CustomerID`

**Expanded**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \{                       '{'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^{}"]*                  any character except: '{', '}', '"' (0
                               or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \{                       '{'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^{}]*                   any character except: '{', '}' (0 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      }                        '}'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "params":                '"params":'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \{                       '{'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^{}"]*                  any character except: '{', '}', '"' (0
                               or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \{                       '{'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^{}]*                   any character except: '{', '}' (0 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      }                        '}'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "CustomerID":"           '"CustomerID":"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^{}"]*                  any character except: '{', '}', '"' (0
                               or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \{                       '{'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^{}]*                   any character except: '{', '}' (0 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      }                        '}'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "href":"                 '"href":"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    &CustomerID=             '&CustomerID='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^{}"]*                  any character except: '{', '}', '"' (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \{                       '{'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^{}]*                   any character except: '{', '}' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    }                        '}'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  }                        '}'
```